# How can I update my table ID (period_id) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

My table name C_InvoicePaySchedule.

```
|period_id | month_name |  duedate     | deff | 
----------------------------------------------
|1000463   | Aug_19     |  2019-08-02  | 1    | 
|1000464   | sep-19     |  2019-09-01  | 1    | 
|1000465   | oct-19     |  2019-10-01  | 1    | 
|1000465   | oct-19     |  2019-10-31  | 0    | 
|1000466   | nov-19     |  2019-11-30  | 1    | 
|1000533   | jun-25     | 2025-06-01   | 1    |
```

I want to see it

```
|period_id | month_name | duedate     | deff | 
----------------------------------------------
|1000463   | Aug_19     | 2019-08-02  | 1    |
|1000464   | sep-19     | 2019-09-01  | 1    |
|1000465   | oct-19     | 2019-10-01  | 1    |
|1000466   | nov-19     | 2019-11-03  | 1    |
|1000467   | dec-19     | 2019-12-03  | 1    |
|1000533   | may-25     | 2025-05-03  | 1    |
```

How can I update period_id?

Comment: Be more specific. Update it from where?

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
UPDATE C_InvoicePaySchedule 
  SET month_name = 'dec-19', 
      duedate  = '2019-12-03' 
WHERE period_id = '1000466;
```

will achieve what I can see in the two Bold lines, hope it will help.

Comment: when I run this update query all period_id is show same id.All month_name is show same name,all duedate is show same date.

Comment: But I want period_id,duedate,month_name as a cont continue sequence.

Comment: Like it  month_name=dec-19,jan-20,feb-20,mar-20,